# Why wont Ubuntu recognize Rogers LTE Rocket stick 330U Sierra wireless modem?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb-modem

I tried to plug the rocket stick into the USB slot, and Ubuntu does not recognize that there is anything in the drive. I plug in a standard USB thumbdrive and it is recognized right away.

Are there any applications to help me open the rogers folders to see the files, and maybe connect to the Internet using said rocket stick 330U?

I've been searching for this answer for almost a week now, seems no one knows how to get the net using this piece of technology.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to enable the "sierra" module. You can do this by typing `sudo modprobe sierra` and then opening up NetworkManager a minute or two later.